# RecyclerView jumps up when touching TextView that is selectable

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, textview

I have a RecyclerView which is populated with items each containing a TextView. I call `textView.setTextIsSelectable(true)` on the TextView to make its text selectable, but I notice that when I tap on the TextView, or long press it to select text, the RecyclerView suddenly scrolls up so that the whole TextView is visible. I want to know how to disable this behaviour, so that touching or long pressing the TextView does not cause any scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

use a custom linear layout manager for the recycler view and override the two requestChildRectangleOnScreen this way

```
override fun requestChildRectangleOnScreen(parent: RecyclerView, child: View, rect: Rect, immediate: Boolean): Boolean {
      return false
    }

    override fun requestChildRectangleOnScreen(parent: RecyclerView, child: View, rect: Rect, immediate: Boolean, focusedChildVisible: Boolean): Boolean {
      return false
    }
```